# How to read a versionCatalog from a *.toml file that is inside a jar

Tags: spring, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

When com.test:version-catalog:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is a *.toml file than it works. But how to read the file when it's part of a jar? Is there a method that extracts the jar and reads a defined file?

Code to read toml file at settings.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from("com.test:version-catalog:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
        }
    }
}
```